# Texas Holdem questions

Tags: no-limit, hand-reading

I have 9spade 5 heart
He has 9clud 2heart
The board is Ah 9h 7h 6h 3h 
Is it a split pot our does my 5h beat the boards 3h for a better flush.

Answer (score 4):

Your flush beats his flush, because you make the better 5-card flush combination:

*your*:
A♥9♥7♥6♥5♥

*his*:
A♥9♥7♥6♥3♥

As you see, you win because one heart of your hole cards is used in combination with the board, givin a better 5-card flush combination. He doesn't even use his extra 2♥ hole card since the board has already `higher ranking cards`, therefore his best hand is the entire board, but you're instead improving the board with your hole card.